# Executing shell commands using ProcessBuilder in linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I have a code which takes some adb commands and reads the input to be later reflected in JTextField. It works fine in windows but in linux, the same code gives a host of errors such as IOexception(No such file or directory). Do we have to specify OS specific environment setup in this case

```
ProcessBuilder process5 = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell","getprop","ro.product.model");   
Process p1 = process5.start();
InputStream stdin1 = p1.getInputStream();
BufferedReader writer1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin1));         
String model=writer1.readLine();
```

Error mgs-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at pb.main(pb.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Is the directory of `adb` in your `PATH` variable? e.g. `export PATH=...`

Comment: It would maybe help if you would paste the exact error message. But could it be that on your linux system the executable `adb` is no not in your `PATH`? If so tell me, then I make this an answer to be accepted by you. To try, just open a terminal and try to execute `adb`. If it is not, add the path to `adb` to your path or create a symlink to `adb` somewhere in your `PATH` like with `ln -s /path/to/adb /usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: @SubOptimal- No. Will i have to do this manually ?

Comment: @Vampire- adb shell getprop ro.product.model - this command works perfectly fine in the terminal . ADB works otherwise

Comment: @vampire- I think the path is not set as u said. Though the Adb commands do run on my terminal without setting anything.

Comment: In the session where you can run `adb`manually, execute just before executing your Java application `export PATH` and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you invoke adb with absolute path?
You can find absolute path with `whereis adb`.
You can also check what `echo $PATH` from **JAVA process builder** returns in order to get same path as Java program.